# What are some primary sources for Chinese restaurants?

Tags: food

I am currently working on a research paper on the history and development of Americanized Chinese food and restaurants, but finding primary sources has been a challenge.

I currently have a few cookbooks, restaurant menus, and Youtube videos with interviews to work with, but I really need numerical data. I would like to know the number of Chinese cuisine restaurants from between the 1870's to the 1950's or so in someplace in California. The records on census.gov don't go to that time and I have tried everything from the Smithsonian research website to ancestry.com but can't seem to find small business data from that time era.

A secondary piece of interest is that one of my cookbook sources appears to be written for an American living in China and spares no pity on instructing the reader how to avoid the filth of China when they cook. This book must have been written for a market, but I can't find anything about Americans migrating to China anywhere. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a particular "someplace in California" in mind?

Comment: Worth noting: what's called Chinese food in Western countries [mostly isn't actually Chinese](https://www.insider.com/chinese-american-food-isnt-from-china-2018-12).

Comment: Have you tried contacting the [*Chinese Historical Society of America*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Historical_Society_of_America)? References from this 2018 paper, [*Sushi in the United States, 1945–1970*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07409710.2017.1420353) might be useful.

Comment: Business directories (look in a research library) would let you count them....

Comment: Or old telephone books from the municipality.

Comment: It seems like what you are looking for here is not so much "primary sources" but "statistical data"? In any event, the easiest way to get to know primary sources is from secondary sources. Read books and articles and see what sources they use. One well known book that might be relevant is [*Chop Suey: A Cultural History of Chinese Food in the United States*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5962225-chop-suey) by Andrew Coe.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy That is kind of true for most popular cuisines when you compare them to the native version.

Comment: If you're interested in the history of Americans in China, you should ask a separate question, but you may be interested in topics such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_International_Settlement